# InkCanvas not working in UWP

Tags: canvas, uwp

I am using InkCanvas, but the InkCanvas not working in inner panel and my code is

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">

    <StackPanel>

        <InkCanvas x:Name="inkCanvas" />

    </StackPanel>

</Grid>
```

The above code working well in WPF, the problem in UWP.

Please suggest me, how to solve this.

Comment: What's the purpose of the StackPanel? Remove it.

Comment: Did you check the [Official UWP Sample App](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/SimpleInk)?

Answer (score 1):

> StackPanel is a layout panel that arranges child elements into a single line that can be oriented horizontally or vertically.
>   By default, StackPanel stacks items vertically from top to bottom in the order they are declared.

For more info, see [Remark of StackPanel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.stackpanel#Remarks).

By default, the `Orientation` of `StackPanel` is `Vertical` that the `ActualHeight` of `InkCanvas` is 0. If you set the `Orientation` of `StackPanel` to `Horizontal` that the `ActualWidth` of `InkCanvas` is 0.

We can't set `VerticalAlignment` to `Stretch` for a child of a `StackPanel` with `Vertical` of `Orientation` that the `ActualHeight` is 0.

If you want to fill exactly the width and height of the window to the `InkCanvas`, we should be able to replace the `StackPanel` by a `Grid`.

If you want to use the `StackPanel` and want to show the `InkCanvas`, you should be able to set `Width` and `Height` of the `InkCanvas`.

Comment: It's my mistake,  I have set the height and width to the InkCanvas. Now it is working.